# Using ajax with paging and a custom sub-query

Tags: query-posts, wp-query, pagination, query, ajax

I have a page that uses three queries to retrieve a variety of content. One of those queries grabs posts that are related to the topic of the page. Since these posts can be of all sorts and related through a variety of methods (various magic fields defined values, their category, etc.) I am using a custom query to grab them (something where I build some args and pass them to WP_Query() like so: `$collected_child_posts = new WP_Query($args);`

Currently I return 5 results at a time (in my args I have `'posts_per_page' => 5`) and I want to page those results using ajax so that only that block of results updates when you click a `MORE POSTS` link.

I implemented this by adding a url to the `MORE POSTS` button that looks like `?paged=n` and then having that retrieved via ajax. Problem is I get the entire page back (including the desired posts) when I only want the posts themselves.

Any ideas on the best way to retrieve just those posts from the subquery without returning the entire page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two options-

load a page fragment using [jQuery's load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (see Loading Page Fragments),

or create your own ajax function to load posts and return it in whatever markup you wish:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_get_posts', 'my_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_get_posts', 'my_ajax_callback');
function my_ajax_callback() {
    $args = $_POST['myargs'];
    $collected_child_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    echo 'some stuff';
    die();
}
```

pass the admin-ajax url to your javascript via [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), or put it directly in your template via `admin_url('admin-ajax.php');`

then call `admin-ajax.php` and pass your ajax action:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.post(your_ajaxurl, {
        action: 'my_ajax_get_posts',
        myargs: args
    },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

the first method is obviously simpler, but the second is easier on the server since a lot less of WP is loaded to execute an ajax call this way, plus less data is getting sent.